# Changing link in SharePoint 2010 Event Calendar

Tags: calendar

On the Event Calendar, if you click on one of the links, it takes you to the DispForm.aspx page. I would like to change that link to go to a custom page but am unable to locate where that change takes place.

Comment: You can try setting your custom page as Calendar List Default Disp Form

Comment: But i have one calendar view linking to the default display form. I want the new calendar view to link to another custom view form... Any ideas?

Comment: One setup i can think of would be having the same amount of calendars as you have custom disp forms, and setting each of the calendars to it's custom dispform and then join them in one master calendar using calendar overlays.

Comment: Sounds interesting, however how do i go about doing this, please not i am new to sharepoint... Also when you say join them in one master calendar does that mean all the appointments will be in one calendar where everyone can see whats on for that month? i didnt want this to be the case, as i wanted separate views. How do i do the overlay bit? sorry...